# question about how to search the occurs times of element in list by lisp

Tags: lisp

If I want to find the occurs times of an element in a long list, what should I do?

for example

```
(input 1 '((l1 (a b c)) (l2 (b a e))))
```

then the result should be `(c e）` since they occur 1 time
also

```
(input 3 '((l1 (a b c)) (l2 (b a e)) (l3 (a b c))))
```

then the result should be `(a b)` since they occur 3 times

and if the input number n larger than the length of L it will return `nil`

```
(if (<(length L) n) nil)
```

Comment: what is the actual question? What did you try so far?

Comment: Your description of the problem, thought not clear, suggests a certain course of action. This looks like homework, so you're gonna have to put in some work yourself. But a rough hint is to *go through the elements* of all the lists, *count the occurrences* and then *only keep those* that occur the right number of times. Your additional condition can be included as preliminary check.

Comment: One trick is that you will have to walk through the list (or lists? not clear).  While doing that you can calculate how long the list is.  Since `length` has to walk the list anyway, you can thus avoid a call to `length`.